# Ruby override initialize method of an array class

Tags: ruby, arrays, initialization, overriding

Basically, I want to have my own array-like class with my own methods.

I would like to initialize it by passing an arguement of the length of an array, and it should instantiate a new array with given length and filled with zeros. So I've written something like this:

```
class Foo < Array
  def initialize(length)
    Array.new(length, 0)
  end
end
```

But when I test this out in IRB i get this:

```
a = Foo.new(5)
=> []
```

I also tried using for-loop to fill this array with zeros n-times, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you inherited from Array you can do this:

```
class Foo < Array
  def initialize(length)
    super(length, 0)
  end
end
```

Note that `super` calls the original `initialize` method on `Array`.

```
Foo.new(5)
#=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `Class#new` looks a bit like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

[Note: in reality, `initialize` is `private`, so it needs to be invoked reflectively, but you get the idea.]

IOW: the return value of `initialize` is completely ignored.

If you want to change the return value of `new`, you need to override `new`. (Kinda obvious, don't you think?) But in this case, it is also possible (and in general a good idea anyway) to simply delegate to the superclass's `initialize`, as in [@spickermann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842087/).